# Getting data from ListView in DialogFragment using onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, fragment, onitemclicklistener, dialogfragment

I currently have a Fragment with an ImageButton that open up a DialogFragment. This DialogFragment is a custom list using an adapter where each entry has an ImageView and TextView.

Is it possible to return the "src" of the ImageView of the selected item to the Fragment that opened the DialogFragment? I need to change the src of the ImageButton to the selected image.

My main Fragment calling the DialogFragment:

```
ImageButton starter = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.imageStarterItem);

starter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Here
                ItemPhysStarterFragment dialog = ItemPhysStarterFragment.newInstance();
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragmentDialog");
            }
        });
```

My DialogFragment class containing the ListView:

```
public class ItemPhysStarterFragment extends DialogFragment {

    Button btn;
    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String[] names={"Bumba's Mask", "Rangda's Mask", "Bluestone Pendant", "Death's Toll",
                    "Mark of the Vanguard", "Swift Wing", "War Flag", "Watcher's Gift"};
    int[] images={R.drawable.bumbas_mask, R.drawable.rangdas_mask, R.drawable.bluestone_pendant, R.drawable.deaths_toll,
                    R.drawable.mark_of_the_vanguard, R.drawable.swift_wing, R.drawable.war_flag, R.drawable.watchers_gift};

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

        //SET TITLE DIALOG TITLE
        getDialog().setTitle("Starter Items");

        //BUTTON,LISTVIEW,SEARCHVIEW INITIALIZATIONS
        lv=(ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        sv=(SearchView) myView.findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
        btn=(Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

        //CREATE AND SET ADAPTER TO LISTVIEW
        final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), this.getItems());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //SEARCH
        sv.setQueryHint("Search starter items..");
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String txt) {
                return false;
            }
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String txt) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(txt);
                return false;
            }
        });

        //BUTTON
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return myView;
    }

    public static ItemPhysStarterFragment newInstance(){
        ItemPhysStarterFragment f = new ItemPhysStarterFragment();
        return f;
    }

    private ArrayList<Item> getItems() {

        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Item item;

        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            item = new Item(names[i], images[i]);
            items.add(item);
        }

        return items;

    }


}
```

Comment: Like with a `Fragment` a `DialogFragment` can communicate using interfaces through the hosting `Activity` - create an interface and just implement the callback in your Activity, and then in your activity find the fragment by its `id` or `tag` and directly call a method passing the value.  There are alternative methods such as RxJava, however this is the usual approach to communicate between `Fragment`s using the hosting `Activity`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an interface first

```
public interface OnListItemClickedListener {
    void onListItemClick(int resourceId);
}
```

Create setter for `interface`

```
public class ItemPhysStarterFragment extends DialogFragment {
     OnListItemClickedListener mListener;

     public void setOnListItemSelectedListener(OnListItemClickedListener listener) {
         this.mListener = listener;
     }
}
```

Now set Listener to your `fragment`

```
ItemPhysStarterFragment dialog = ItemPhysStarterFragment.newInstance();
dialog.setOnListItemSelectedListener(new OnListItemClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onListItemClick(int resourceId) {
                // User your resourceId
            }
        });
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragmentDialog");
```

Final step, trigger listener in your `ItemPhysStarterFragment` fragment's ListItemClick() -

```
...public void onListItemClick(int resourceId) {
        mListener.onListItemClick(pass your resource id);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please clarify what you are referring to for "resource id"?

Comment: That will be your drawable resource id to be returned on List item click. i.e. `R.drawable.bumbas_mask`

Comment: Thank you so much Wizard! I finally got the code to work so I can finalize my app. Couldn't have done it without your help

Comment: Pleasure to help you. If someone's answer helped you, don't forget to upvote it. And if answer is correct you can accept it as well.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://androidstudio2.blogspot.com/2014/05/example-of-dialog-fragment-with.html) was helpful to me in achieving the same result as proposed by @Wizzard.

It is basically proposing the same solution, except there is not need to create a custom interface.

1. In your `fragment class` create a variable and setter method to accept `OnItemClickListener`

   ```
   private android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
   ```

   `public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {`
        `this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;`
      `}`
2. In the `fragement class` make sure the `listView` sets the item click listener:

   `list.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);`
3. Finally in you `main class` you can call the `listviewItemClickListener`:

   `DialogMyListFragment df = new DialogMyListFragment().getInstance();`
   `df.setOnItemClickListener(listener);`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an interface

```
public interface OnCustomItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(final String src);
}
```

and implement that interface when creating your dialog

```
(...),new OnCustomItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClicked() {
                        //do something
                        }
                    }, (...)
```

and handle it appropriately on your ItemPhysStarterFragment class